# mysql table formatting and infile issue

Tags: mysql

Each time I go and create my table and then add the .csv file, it keeps not fully loading in all of the data. Below is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Parts_Maintenance (
Vehicle_ID BIGINT(20),
State VARCHAR(255),
Repair VARCHAR(255),
Reason VARCHAR(255),
Year YEAR,
Make VARCHAR(255),
Body_Type VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Vehicle_ID)
);
```

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/FleetMaintenanceRecords.csv'
INTO TABLE Parts_Maintenance
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

```
SELECT * FROM Parts_Maintenance;
```

Here is a photo of what it looks like in Codio:

[image]

And here is a photo of some of the data being brought in:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Tried to create table and bring in a .csv file. Table was created but the data is not all there and the table looks messed up

Comment: Your `LINES TERMINATED BY` is probably wrong, it's probably  `\r`.

Comment: I'll try that right now, thank you!

Comment: Did you make your CSV file with windows?? Try to use **LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'**

Comment: So the \r fixed one issue but now I am getting the value '0' returned for all rows under Vehicle_ID. Thoughts?

Comment: Try to import using input preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @barmer Your LINES TERMINATED BY is probably wrong, it's probably `\r`

You May use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/FleetMaintenanceRecords.csv'
INTO TABLE Parts_Maintenance
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Alternatively, you can use another method with workbench.

- Right Click on Table

  - Table data import wizard

  - Choose the file path
- Select the destination table

  - Check and configure import settings

  - Click on Next to execute.

This is the best and simple solution.